# Moving bookmarks crashes Adobe Acrobat X Pro

Tags: adobe-acrobat, bookmarks

Since a few weeks ago, every time I move a bookmark, Adobe Acrobat X Pro crashes.
I have found no info on the web of a similar problem.

**Any ideas/suggestions to fix this?**

Comment: That is a very old version of Acrobat. I have an older Windows 7 VM and it has Acrobat XI and that is also out of support. Have you tried reinstalling Acrobat?  Uninstall it, restart, and install it and patch it.

Comment: No I haven't tried reinstalling. I was hoping first to try understanding the cause for this. As said, it was working fine until recently. I don't see any reason for it not to work.

Comment: Someone might have this around. I haven't seen it for about a decade.